# REPLACE statement targeting a child element

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to use REPLACE to target a child element of a STRUCT?

Ideally it would work as shown below:

```
WITH sub1 AS (
    SELECT STRUCT('foo' as name) data UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT('bar')
)
SELECT * REPLACE(2 as data.name) FROM sub1
```

Currently it will trigger the following error:
`Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "." at [5:27]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an interesting solution:

```
WITH sub1 AS (
    SELECT STRUCT('foo' AS name, 1 AS id) data UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT('bar', 2)
)
SELECT data.* REPLACE('replacement name' AS name) FROM sub1
```

PRO: this solution avoid to type all fields (very convenient when you have a lot of them)

CON: the tradeoff is that the output structure is changed.
I'm still searching for a way to nest it again without listing all fields

If you really need to keep the structure though you can use the following query (courtesy of Danny Kitt):

```
WITH sub1 AS (
    SELECT STRUCT('foo' AS name, 1 AS id) data UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT('bar', 2)
)
SELECT data FROM (SELECT data.* REPLACE('replacement name' AS name) FROM sub1) data
```

To put some light on this use case: this kind of query is very useful when you want be generate fixtures with few moving fields as follow:

```
WITH 
fixture AS (
    SELECT id FROM UNNEST([1,2,3,4,5]) id
),
template AS (
    SELECT STRUCT(
        NULL AS id,
        NULL AS name,
        NULL AS field3,
        NULL AS field4,
        NULL AS field5,
        NULL AS field6,
        NULL AS field7
    ) data
)
SELECT data FROM (SELECT data.* REPLACE(
    fixture.id AS id,
    CONCAT("name", CAST(fixture.id AS STRING)) AS name
) FROM template,fixture) data
```

Comment: Table values can be treated as structs, so changing your query to the following should create a struct as you're looking for: `SELECT struct_name FROM (SELECT data.* REPLACE('replacement name' AS name) FROM sub1) struct_name`

Answer (score 0):

for your particular example - try

```
WITH sub1 AS (
  SELECT STRUCT('foo' as name) data UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT('bar')
)
SELECT * REPLACE(2 as data) FROM sub1
```

See below more generic example

```
WITH sub1 AS (
    SELECT STRUCT('foo' AS name, 1 AS id) data UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT('bar', 2)
)
SELECT * REPLACE(STRUCT('replacement name' AS name, data.id) AS data) 
FROM sub1
```